# ASP.NET Web API 2 CRUD Operation with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a MS Web API 2 project. I have created my Entity Framework in a separate project and am referencing it in my API. Reading over a few tutorials, it is suggested that:

*"ideally, we should not return EF entity objects from the Web API. It is recommended to return DTO (Data Transfer Object) from Web API".*

Hence, I have created my model in my API:

```
namespace MyAPI.Models
{
  [Table("Customer")]
  public class CustomerViewModel
  {
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

My question is: **Do I need to create a data context class for each model in my API or is it fine to use EF context class?** And if I do need to create a separate context for each model, **how can I achieve this by a reference to the EF context class?** Below is what I have started with:

```
namespace MyAPI.Models
{
   public class CustomerDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public CustomerDbContext() : base("name=CusetomerDbContext")
       {
       }

       public DbSet<MyEFDataAccess.Customer> CustomerViewModel { get; set; }
   }
}
```

And my Controller is:

```
namespace MyAPI.Controllers
{
   public class CustomersController : ApiController
   {
    private readonly CustomerDbContext _context = new CustomerDbContext();

    // GET: api/Customer
    public IQueryable<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomerViewModels()
    {
        return _context.CustomerViewModel;
    }
}
```

The above correctly throws an error because it cannot convert EF customer to CustomerViewModel directly!

Comment: you show two unrelated pieces of code. Please show the code where you're attempting to use them together.

Comment: @cwharris Edited my post

Comment: *"It is recommended to return DTO (Data Transfer Object) from Web API"* - that's not at all what it is trying to say to you: you should have **two separated** classes for your entity (used with entity framework) and for your API (your DTO), and then **map** one object to the other: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ideally, we should not return EF entity objects from the Web API. It
>   is recommended to return DTO (Data Transfer Object) from Web API.

The reason for this is to make sure you can change your DB schema without changing API, and vice versa. If you accomplish that goal, then you've adhered to that given advice.

The problem you're having is basic. Type `A` cannot be implicitly converted to Type `B`. As far as the compiler is concerned, you're trying to convert a `DbContext` to a `FormControl`, and it has no idea how to do that. You need to tell it explicitly what to do. One example, albeit not great:

```
public DbSet<MyEFDataAccess.Customer> Customer { get; set; }
```

and

```
public IQueryable<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomerViewModels()
{
    return _context.Customer.Select(
        customer => new CustomerViewModel
        {
            // <assign properties here>
        }
    );
}
```

That being said, returning an `IQueryable<T>` from your Controller is a definite no-no. You definitely want to allow for the consumer to query specific records. You could do this to enable pagination, for instance:

```
public async Task<List<CustomerViewModel>> GetCustomerViewModels(
    int skip = 0,
    int take = 100
)
{
    return await _context.Customer
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .Select(
            customer => new CustomerViewModel
            {
                // <assign properties here>
            }
        )
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: "easy" is not a word I would use to describe DB schema changes. You can get used to it, but that doesn't make it inherently easy. EntityFramework provides the ability to generate Migrations, which it uses each time (generally speaking) the DbContext is generated. It checks a hash in the DB to see what version of the DbContext you're running, and then upgrades the DB if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the conclusion is to have our own model and dbContext classes for each object in the API and then assign them explicitly. 

Now, can you please give me an example where you want to change the DB without the need modify the API. My confusion is if I add a new column to table Customer I will still need to modify the CustomerViewModel as well as the CustomersController. Do I not?

Comment: A `DbContext` represents a DB. Have one for each *database*. A `DbSet<>` represents a DB Table. You'll have as many of these as you need in a single DB / DbContext to support a normalized relational data model. But lets say you want to add a field to a table in your DB (a property on your Entity model), but you don't want that property to show up in your API responses - *that* is why you need two separate classes to represent the same "thing".

Comment: The way I like to reconcile having two classes for the same "thing" is like this: Classes are not real world things. They are *representative* of real world things. A Database is designed to store data from real world things, so for EntityFramework to work, we have to have a class that represents the *data*, and therefore *indirectly* the thing. Your API also represents the thing, but perhaps it represents it differently. A sheet of paper may have "First Name: Bob". A database may have table:person column:firstName value:Bob, and your API model might use "GivenName". Different representations.

Comment: For each given representation of the data, you should have a different class. But you should only have as many representations as is helpful for you, and you should probably have some "source of truth" representation that all of the others convert to/from (even if that's multiple normalized tables in a database).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If I may, let me ask you about this part of your answer: "returning an IQueryable from your Controller is a definite no-no. You definitely want to allow for the consumer to query specific records.". If that is the case, why is it offered by the controller by default? Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` is not supported by ASP.NET MVC Controllers. `IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable`, and MVC supports `IEnumerable`. When you enumerate through a queryable, it executes its query and yields the results. The API endpoint in your question would have *always returned every record from the database*. Which is almost certainly not what you had in mind... considering databases could contain millions of rows.

Comment: @cwharris What? ASP.NET MVC **certainly** supports `IQueryable<T>`. It **is** a terrible idea to return them directly due to the disposal of the context in a proper implementation, but it is certainly possible to do so with for example a singleton context. Also, the `ToListAsync` in this answer returns every single item as well, so your comment makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `skip` and `take` do nothing then, I suppose? Forgot about OData support. You’re right about that.

Comment: How do I define _context? I am asking this because I am now getting errors for _Context.Entry and _Context.Dispose and _Context.Cutomer.FindAsync?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'd also like to point out that ASP.NET MVC doesn't have OData support enabled by default, so OP needed to know nothing about that at this point in time. So technically it was converting to an IEnumerable.

Comment: I am not sure why you brought up OData... What I meant is not related to it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Can you explain how `IQueryable` is relevant in ASP.NET MVC aside from OData query support? What exactly did you mean?

Comment: What I said is that you can have an Action that returns `IQueryable` directly, although a pretty terrible idea

Comment: Yeah, and it's supported only because it inherits from `IEnumerable` (outside of OData query support), and what I said was the easiest way to express that.

Comment: @amindomeniko you should create a new question for that topic, or find one that already exists.